# Как скопировать данные удаленной бд и сохранить их локально?

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite

Дооброго времени суток).У меня есть бд (MySQL) на хостинге.
БД подключена к сайту, по совместительству хочу там хранить некоторые данные для приложения, но скорее всего под это будет вторая бд.
В целом, я хочу реализовать копирование данных из удаленной MySql бд в локальную Sqlite с последующим сохранением полученных данных.
Вопрос с подключением вроде бы решен, я буду использовать jdbc модуль в приложении для подключения к бд.
В остальном нужен метод копирования и записи данных в локальную бд.
С этим как раз таки проблема, я не очень хорошо владею Java.
Подскажите варианты реализации и/или мануалы для ознакомления.
***google, меня забанил и не дает нужных ответов :'(***

Comment: А почему бы не использовать MySql и локально? Можно поднять в доккере. Тогда задача сводится к сделал бэкап на сервере, скачал, развернул локально.

Comment: Скопировать нужно один раз? `mysqldump` в этом поможет

Comment: мне нужно единоразово получить данные из бд.
на сколько я знаю android работает с sqlite, поэтому и спрашивал про него. В дальнейшем хочу сделать проверку локальных данных  с данными в удаленной бд и при несовпадении с данными на удаленном сервере обновлять информацию в локальной бд

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы для этого посоветовал использовать Room. Это настройка над SQLite.

А вообще я бы посоветовал использовать Android Architecture. Это связка Room, ViewModel, и Livedata.

Таким образом если еще использовать библиотеку Retrofit, тем самым можно скачивать загружать данные с удаленного сервера и сохранять с заменой в Room. Получается у нас постоянная база данных, которая работает без интернета, а при включении интернета скачивает обновления с удаленной СУБД. Нужно только реализовать API. На php я использовал SLIM.
Почитай тут [ссылка](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/). В интернете много примеров. У меня самого есть приложение, но оно на kotlin

Answer (score 1):

Для получения данных с удаленно БД можно воспользоватся любой утилитой которая умеет делать дампы. Например консольная утилита `mysqldump`, либо же воспользоваться `Mysql Workbench` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import.html).
Если нужно, то можно повторно выгружать данные с удаленной БД и заменять все данные в локальной БД.

**UPD**. Подправил в соответствиис замечаниями в комментариях

Comment: sqlite поддерживает и транзакции, и внешние ключи.

Comment: Возможно я немного отстал от прогресса